# How to filter SSAS catalog list?

Tags: sql, ssas, dmv, dmx-ssas

I use DMX query like this

```
SELECT * FROM $SYSTEM.DBSCHEMA_CATALOGS
```

which retrieves list of OLAP DBs.
I would like to add a `where` clause to select catalogs where name contains some sequence of chars, e.g.,

```
SELECT * FROM $SYSTEM.DBSCHEMA_CATALOGS
WHERE [CATALOG_NAME] LIKE '%FOO%'
```

Any ideas on how to filter the retrieved list of Catalog names given the [limitation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh230820.aspx)?

> Notably, JOIN, GROUP BY, LIKE, CAST, and CONVERT are not supported.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it is Analysis Services Multidimensional not Tabular you can install [ASSP](http://asstoredprocedures.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Installation%20Instructions&referringTitle=Home) and use the `ASSP.DMV` function which implements the LIKE clause in the WHERE clause. Here is an [example](http://asstoredprocedures.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=DMV&referringTitle=XmlaDiscover) on a different DMV.